# Application Specific Log file(SLF4J) not being updated in Jboss As 7.1

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, slf4j

My Requirement is to create a Project specific Log file, but while deploying application caa-web.log file is created in server logs folder. But all the logs are updated in server.log only.

Dependency jars:

```
slf4j-log4j12
slf4j-api
jcl-over-slf4j
```

Log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    debug="false">
    <appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/caa-web.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="25MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="Append" value="false" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c %x - %L %m%n" />
            <!-- <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" /> -->
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.